# XADES4J: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature

Tags: java, jdeveloper, xades4j

When runing app using XADES4J I get this error, someone has any clue about what is happening? I let you down below the code, the libary list and the error stacktrace. If someone could help me I would be so thankfull.

```
private static void signBes(Document doc) throws Exception {
       Element elem = doc.getDocumentElement();
       DOMHelper.useIdAsXmlId(elem);

       KeyingDataProvider kdp = new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider("PKCS12","C:\\******\\******.pfx",new FirstCertificateSelector(),new DirectPasswordProvider("******"),new DirectPasswordProvider("******"),true);
       DataObjectDesc obj = new DataObjectReference("#" + elem.getAttribute("Id")).withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform()); 
       SignedDataObjects dataObjs = new SignedDataObjects().withSignedDataObject(obj);
       XadesBesSigningProfile signingProfile = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kdp);
       
       XadesSigner signer = signingProfile.newSigner();
       //Here throws the error -> signer.sign(dataObjs, elem);
    
       TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
       Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
       DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);        
       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/aTicketBAI_firmat.xml"));
       transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

[Library List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAYXu.png)

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:394)
> at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
> at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$3.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:175)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
> at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
> at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:112)
> at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilterInternal(JpsAbsFilter.java:293)
> at
> oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:150)
> at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
> at
> oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
> at
> oracle.jrf.servlet.ExtensibleGlobalFilter.doFilter(ExtensibleGlobalFilter.java:92)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3797)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3763)
> at
> weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:344)
> at
> weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2451)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2299)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1720)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1680)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
> at
> weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
> at
> weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
> at
> weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
> at
> weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
> at
> weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
> at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)  at
> weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360) Caused by:
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;Lorg/w3c/dom/Element;)V
> at xades4j.production.SignerBES.createSignature(SignerBES.java:320)
> at xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:164)    at
> xades4j.production.SignerBES.sign(SignerBES.java:127)     at
> ccalgir.webservice.wsticketbai.ticketBAI.signBes(ticketBAI.java:813)
> at
> ccalgir.webservice.wsticketbai.ticketBAI.generateTicketBAI(ticketBAI.java:722)
> at ccalgir.webservice.wsticketbai.ticketBAI.doGet(ticketBAI.java:72)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)     at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
> at
> weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:353)
> ... 36 more

**I looked for the method inside of my xmlsec-2.2.0 library, I found it the same method that is giving the error "XMLSignature(Document p1, String p2, Element p3, Element p4)". I have this method, but however when I run it, it doesn't find it.**

Comment: You recently asked about a similar error. How did you solve that one? Could it be a similar cause? Could you have another dependency that is puling a different version of Apache xmlsec indirectly? Just throwing out ideas..

Comment: The last problem that I had it was caused by guice libarary, version 2.0 don't cointains the method (checkNotNull), just changed the version of guice to 4.2 and guice multibindings too. Im thinking now, about my XML structrue. I maybe need some specific structure to place the signature? Or the XADES4J does everything for you.

Comment: xades4j handles the XMLSignature element itself.and appends it to the DOM element supplied to the sign() method

Comment: @lgoncalves The part of the next code on bold should return me something? In that case what it should return? "DataObjectDesc obj = new DataObjectReference("#" + **elem.getAttribute("Id")**).withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform());".

Comment: Does your document element have an ID? If so, it should return something. Also note that for same document references by ID to work property, you need to set the ID attribute as a XML attribute using Node. setIdAttributeNS

Comment: Hi @lgoncalves , I added this lane of code to my xml creation process, **rootElement.setAttributeNS("", "Id", "root");**, so now I have an "Id" attribute only on root element of the XML, now the **elem.getAttribute("Id")** returns me "root". But the **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature** keeps appearing when run. I really don't know what to do. You have any more clue about what is happening? Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: I have no further clue, sorry :/